# how to delete items from NSArray to create a filtered array (NSPredicate)

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

I got a NSArray that i m fetching from my database and i was using kinda brute force solution where i needed to modify the content of my database for each element. I was using this NSPredicate to filter my array

```
NSArray *array = [haveIngArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %@ contains[cd] self", recipeIngredientsArray]];
```

where recipeIngredientArray are the input came from user and haveIngArray are the fetched content.

this is a sample of the content of my database

```
1 piece of chicken breast
3 spoon of wheat
6 glass of water
1 can of corn
1 glass of lemon juice
salt
```

i will compare the inputs with the content came from database but i don't need to compare certain things like salt, water,pepper. How can i delete these from my array so i can use my real filter?

I tried to use NSPredicate with contain and delete the same objects from the original array but that cause performance issues.

Comment: You want to delete records in your array that contain specific words, like: salt water etc..?

Comment: @judge, is it possible, that you use two profiles on Stack Overflow? Or why does this user even use the same [variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313382/how-to-compare-2-nsarrays-like-nspredicate-contains). BTW: if you have code with performance issues you should post it.

Comment: @DekelMaman yes thats what i want.

Comment: can I ask you again to give us your faulty code?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.I was inspecting the other users account :) that was very bizzare.I was just comparing using NSSet to compare and if there is match delete it.Which was so brute force that i felt like there have to be a better way

Comment: NSSet sounds good to me, but to see your problems there you will have to show the code.

Comment: @judge. are you aware of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23313505/106435). Same applies to your: create proper model objects, and use set and predicate operations. you would want to have another set `basics` that contains water, pepper and salt.

Comment: @vikingosegundo that was the bizarre part.I was working exactly what you wrote for that user.Wow what are the odds

Comment: but does your teacher give your rules for variable names?

Comment: Nope just description, what is needed what should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hop This help you ...
Just get your DB into MutableArray, then filter it by any words you want

```
//enter the words you want to filter by
NSArray *filterArray = @[@"water",@"salt"];

NSArray *dataBaseArray = @[@"1 piece of chicken breast", @"3 spoon of wheat", @"6 glass of water", @"1 can of corn", @"1 glass of lemon juice",@"1 piece of chicken breast", @"3 spoon of wheat", @"6 glass of water", @"1 can of corn", @"1 glass of lemon juice"];

// this is the array that get the records from the DB
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i <dataBaseArray.count; i++) {

    NSString *str = dataBaseArray[i];
    BOOL found = NO;
    for (NSString *word in filterArray) {

        if ([str rangeOfString:word].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            found = YES;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        [tempArray addObject:str];
    }

}

dataBaseArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:tempArray];
```